# Center each image within a image slider in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

/* Hi, I have a basic slider with images in the HTMl, with css I can style it perfectly when the images have the same size. Unfortunately when some picture is wider he takes the center for the widest picture also for them who have less width. My question is: can I take for one picture at a time the margin auto and where to place it? */

```
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".sliderzps > Img.1").fadeIn(300);
startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
count = $(".sliderzps > Img").size();


loop = setInterval(function() {

if(sliderNext > count) {
    sliderNext = 1; 
    sliderInt= 1;

}

$(".sliderzps > Img").fadeOut(0);
$(".sliderzps > Img." + sliderNext).fadeIn(0);
sliderInt = sliderNext;
$(".sliderzps > Img.1").css({"margin-left": "auto", "margin-right": "auto"});
sliderNext = sliderNext +1;
}, 3000)
}
var main = function () {
"use strict";
/* code hier */};
```

Comment: Why are all your `$` characters enclosed in `?

Comment: struggled with the site its the first time that I ask a question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this my code:

```js
sliderInt = 1;
sliderNext = 2;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sliderzps > img").hide();
    $(".sliderzps > img").eq(0).fadeIn(0);
    startSlider();
});

function startSlider(){
    count = $(".sliderzps > img").size();
    loop = setInterval(function() {
    if(sliderNext >= count) {
        sliderNext = 0; 
    }
    $(".sliderzps > img").fadeOut(0);
    $(".sliderzps > img").eq(sliderNext).fadeIn(0);
    sliderInt = sliderNext;
    sliderNext++;
    }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.sliderzps{
    width:200px;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid #323232;
    padding:5px;
}
img{
    margin:auto;
    width:40px;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderzps">
<img src="http://www.clarkcraft.co.uk/images/des/48040.jpg"/>
<img src="http://glamorouslymommy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/small-background1.jpg"/>
<img src="https://d21buns5ku92am.cloudfront.net/26027/images/149697-Symbid_logo_square_blue_bg_500px-a46cbc-medium-1416847903.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice with your code i have more freedom in my css, thanks it works for me now!